# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined ERROR on Scene.js

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I have been working on building react-native apps for a few months now. Recently, I have been getting this error when I run my app for `iOS`. Looks like an error in the `Scene.js` file. Has anyone faced a similar issue? Any directions here is much appreciated.

I am using react-native version `0.40.0`.

[Update] Did some research and found the root of this issue. The issue has been since the new version of `react-native-router-flux` version 3.39. There is an issue raised on their `github` page as well https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1926

[image: Scene.js ERROR]

Comment: I solved this by reverting `react-native-router-flux` back to `3.38.0`. Thanks